# How aggregate by value in apache spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark

i have sucess read cassandra from spark, using this syntax :

```
val rddSelect = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "nametable").select("column1", "column2").take(100)
```

i need to do aggregate group by column1 and column2 in spark

i have tried groupbykey and another transformations, but it's error :

```
value reduceByKey is not a member of Array[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]
```

maybe anyone can give me a clue, thx

NB : i use scala

Comment: It is an array, not a map, so it doesn't have keys, and doesn't have xxxByKey methods. try just `groupBy`

Comment: Hi @Shadowlands , if i want to use reduceByKey or anything bykey, i must use map before, right ?

Comment: @Shadowlands 

`val a = rddSelect.map(t => (t,1))
val b = a.reduceByKey((k,v) => v+1)`

Comment: @ihsansat  Are you sure you want the "take(100)" (thereby converting to from RDD to simple Array) instead of just performing the aggregate on the rdd? Of course, you still have to map to (key, value) in order to perform xxxByKey operations, but if you do the operations on the rdd it will run in parallel across the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this -

```
val modifiedRDD = rddSelect.toJavaRDD.rdd
  .map { x =>
    {

      val temp = x.get(0).toString().split(",")
      (temp(0), temp(1))
    }
  }

modifiedRDD.groupBy(func)
modifiedRDD.reduceByKey(func)
```